# OR in the group by fields in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have these 2 queries in psql :

```
select a.name, a.port, count(a.id) as cont 
from a 
group by a.name, a.port 
order by cont desc 
limit 5;

select a.name, a.ip, count(a.id) as cont 
from a 
group by a.name, a.ip 
order by cont desc 
limit 5;
```

and I want to write a query to get top 5 records by count across these 2 groups and display their a.name, count, a.port/a.ip fields. Does anyone know how to structure this query?

I want something like this:

```
select a.name, a.port or a.ip, count(a.id) as cont 
from a 
group by a.name, a.port or a.ip 
order by cont desc 
limit 5;
```

Any guidance on how to do this in postgres is appreciated.

Comment: When you say: *I have these 2 queries in psql* do you mean that they work? Because you can't select a column like name without having it also in the group by clause.

Comment: sorry, my bad, updated the question to reflect correct queries.

Comment: To clarify what you want you must post sample data and expected results because your requirement is still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `port`/`ip` have compatible types, then a lateral join is the best solution:

```
select a.name, v.which, v.val, count(*) as cont
from a cross join lateral
     (values ('ip', ip), ('port', port)
     ) v(which, val)
group by a.name, v.which, v.val
order by cont desc
limit 5;
```

If these do not have the same type, you can use `::text` to convert them to strings:

```
     (values ('ip', ip::text), ('port', port::text)
     ) v(which, val)
```

Comment: This is amazing. It worked, some minor edits in the select statement to select same fields as group by clause. lateral join is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Take the best rows from union of both resultsets:

```
with p as (
  select a.name, a.port, count(a.id) as cont from a group by a.name, a.port
), i as (
  select a.name, a.ip  , count(a.id) as cont from a group by a.name, a.ip
)
select name, discriminator || '=' || coalesce(port,ip) as port_or_ip, cont
from (
  select name, port, null as ip, cont, 'port' as discriminator from p
  union
  select name, null as port, ip, cont, 'ip'   as discriminator from i
)
order by cont desc
limit 5;
```

(I didn't try, probably some casts will be needed.)